# Reinstalled Mac OS X on my MacBook Air & now it won't let me install iMovie and iPhoto?

Tags: macbook-pro, upgrade, mac-appstore, apple-id, macos

I get this weird error message after reinstalling Mac OS X on my Macbook Air[image: Weird error message]

> These apps cannot be accepted by your Apple ID. These apps were
>   recently assigned to another Apple ID, and they will be available in
>   that Apple ID's Purchase list. If you don't have access to that Apple
>   ID and want to receive future updates, you will need to purchase the
>   application.

I don’t even know what these apps are, I've never used them, although I might 
one day.

I’ve got one other machine, which I bought myself—the MacBook Air is for work—and I sign into the app store on my account; I buy software and expense it.

But the error seems strange and the update behavior seems a bit wrong. As you can see I've already upgraded to Yosemite, yet the app store is getting busy, downloading all 5GB of the update all over again.

[image: getting busy reinstalling what I've already got]

I've seen some really strange behavior with the app store over the last while so I'm curious if this is a bug, or just some policy I don't understand or am unaware of.

Any ideas appreciated, thanks!

## update

It's was just a glitch in the App store, the applications had been installed, it seems one hand doesn't know what the other is doing.

Comment: This is possible if the computer was given to you by your employer, (you didn't purchase it yourself, that is,) and it came preconfigured with software downloaded under another AppleID. Could this be the situation?

Comment: Going forward - this won't be an issue since the apps are now free downloads to all: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/280764/how-do-i-get-iwork-imovie-garage-band-free-of-charge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## update

It's was just a glitch in the App store, the applications had been installed, it seems one hand doesn't know what the other is doing.

Answer (score 0):

I got this same error today and found out that iMovie and iPhoto are connected to my original @me.com apple id (from years ago).  I now use a different email with app store.  You have to log out of the app store with your current apple id and log in with your original (older) id (assuming that you have/had one).